# Jinja2 templating issue

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Trying to set a fact in ansible using Jinja2.

Getting the following error

Error: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got ':'

PFB code

```
- set_fact:
    lb_lstnr_map: []

- name: "Build listeners map"
  set_fact:
    lb_lstnr_map: >-
      {%- if item == 443 and cert_arn -%}
        {{  lb_lstrn_map.extend({
          'Protocol': 'HTTPS',
          'Port': 443,
          'DefaultActions': [ { 'Type': 'forward', 'TargetGroupName': tg_name } ],
          'SslPolicy': ssl_policy,
          'Certificates': [ { 'CertificateArn': cert_arn } ] })
         }}
        {%- else -%}
        {{  lb_lstrn_map.extend({
          'Protocol': 'TCP' if lb_type = 'network' else 'HTTP',
          'Port': item,
          'DefaultActions': [ {'Type': 'forward', 'TargetGroupName': tg_name } ]
          }
          })
        }}
      {% endif %}
  with_items: lb_listeners
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the syntax for lists and dicts when you extend `lb_lstrn_map`. And for dicts you should use update, not extend. It should be something like:

```
lb_lstrn_map.update({'Protocol': 'HTTPS', 'Port': 443,
                       'DefaultActions': {
                       ['Type': 'forward', 'TargetGroupName': tg_name ]
                       },
                      'SslPolicy': ssl_policy,
                      'Certificates': ['CertificateArn': cert_arn],
                    })
```

Comment: I have changed it as suggested but still same error

Answer (score 0):

The braces are not balanced

```
        {{  lb_lstrn_map.extend({
          'Protocol': 'TCP' if lb_type = 'network' else 'HTTP',
          'Port': item,
          'DefaultActions': [ {'Type': 'forward', 'TargetGroupName': tg_name } ]
          }
          })
        }}
```

Correct syntax

```
        {{  lb_lstrn_map.extend({
          'Protocol': 'TCP' if lb_type = 'network' else 'HTTP',
          'Port': item,
          'DefaultActions': [ {'Type': 'forward', 'TargetGroupName': tg_name } ]
          })
        }}
```